# Python equivalent of D3.js

Tags: python, graph, d3.js, graph-tool

Can anyone recommend a Python library that can do **interactive** graph visualization?

I specifically want something like [d3.js](https://d3js.org/) but for `python` and ideally it would be 3D as well.

I have looked at:

- [NetworkX](https://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) - it only does `Matplotlib` plots and those seem to be 2D. I didn't see any sort of interactiveness, like one that `d3.js` gives, such as pulling nodes around.
- [graph-tool](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/) - it does only 2D plots and has very slow *interactive* graphs.

Comment: You would want to generate a graph in networkx and then manipulate in d3.js, if you're looking for a browser based version.

Comment: @kreativitea ok .... how would I do that o-o ideally:

Graph Data (via API Calls in Python) -> Python (Machine Learning Stuffs) -> Django / Something + D3.js (visualization) -> Pretty pictures and website :)

Comment: I think you can implement vega lite in python. Check this out and plotly of course.

Answer (score 81):

You could use [d3py](https://github.com/mikedewar/d3py) a python module that generate xml pages embedding d3.js script. For example :

```
import d3py
import networkx as nx

import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edge(1,2)
G.add_edge(1,3)
G.add_edge(3,2)
G.add_edge(3,4)
G.add_edge(4,2)

# use 'with' if you are writing a script and want to serve this up forever
with d3py.NetworkXFigure(G, width=500, height=500) as p:
    p += d3py.ForceLayout()
    p.show()
```

Comment: Worked for me, but I had to edit one of the lines to `with d3py.NetworkXFigure(G, width=500, height=500, host="localhost") as p:`. I checked out the latest commit of _d3py_ at github (SHA: 4e92a90f4003370bc086e0f57b19fca1bd4e8fba)

Comment: Unfortunately d3py isn't being actively developed any more - Vincent is the modern equivalent (a Python interface to Vega/d3.js) but psychemedia's answer below (export networkx to json then render in d3.js) might be the cleanest.

Comment: Try https://altair-viz.github.io/ - the successor of d3py and vincent. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/49695472/179014 .

Answer (score 55):

Plotly supports interactive 2D and 3D graphing. Graphs are rendered with D3.js and can be created with a [Python API](https://plot.ly/python), [matplotlib](https://plot.ly/python/matplotlib-to-plotly-tutorial/), [ggplot for Python](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/msund/11349097), [Seaborn](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/msund/11349097), [prettyplotlib](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/msund/11349097), and [pandas](https://plot.ly/ipython-notebooks/big-data-analytics-with-pandas-and-sqlite/). You can zoom, pan, toggle traces on and off, and see data on the hover. Plots can be embedded in HTML, apps, dashboards, and IPython Notebooks. Below is a [temperature graph](http://moderndata.plot.ly/update-plotly-charts-with-cron-jobs-and-python/) showing interactivity. See the gallery of [IPython Notebooks](https://plot.ly/ipython-notebooks/) [tutorials](http://moderndata.plot.ly/) for more examples.

[image]

The [docs](https://plot.ly/python/) provides examples of supported plot types and code snippets.

[image]


Specifically to your question, you can also [make interactive plots](https://plot.ly/ipython-notebooks/network-graphs/) from NetworkX. 


[image]


For 3D plotting with Python, you can make 3D scatter, line, and surface plots that are similarly interactive. Plots are rendered with WebGL. For example, see [a 3D graph](https://plot.ly/~MattSundquist/11399/uk-swap-rates/) of UK Swap rates.

[image]

Disclosure: I'm on the Plotly team.

Comment: Clearly the question aims at **graphs** in the sense of nodes connected by edges. This answer needlessly includes other visualization capabilities of plotly.

Comment: @mateo-sanchez it is very unfortunate that Plotly has decided to terminate all academic and individual subscriptions to focus on corporate clients

Answer (score 22):

Have you looked at vincent?  Vincent takes Python data objects and converts them to Vega visualization grammar.  Vega is a higher-level visualization tool built on top of D3.  As compared to D3py, the vincent repo has been updated more recently.  Though the examples are all static D3.

more info:

- https://github.com/wrobstory/vincent
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/vincent/0.1.6

---

The graphs can be viewed in Ipython, just add this code

```
vincent.core.initialize_notebook()
```

Or output to JSON where you can view the JSON output graph in the Vega online editor (http://trifacta.github.io/vega/editor/) or view them on your Python server locally.  More info on viewing can be found in the pypi link above.

Not sure when, but the Pandas package should have D3 integration at some point.  http://pandas.pydata.org/developers.html

Bokeh is a Python visualization library that supports interactive visualization. Its primary output backend is HTML5 Canvas and uses client/server model.

examples: http://continuumio.github.io/bokehjs/

Comment: [Vincent is on the way out](https://github.com/wrobstory/vincent#status) - looks like there are some replacements, but I'm not sure how closely tied to ipython they will be..

Answer (score 20):

One recipe that I have used (described here: [Co-Director Network Data Files in GEXF and JSON from OpenCorporates Data via Scraperwiki and networkx](http://blog.ouseful.info/2013/02/25/co-director-network-data-files-in-gexf-and-json-from-opencorporates-data-via-scraperwiki/) ) runs as follows:

- generate a network representation using *networkx*
- export the network as a JSON file
- import that JSON into to *[d3.js](http://d3js.org/)*. (*networkx* can export both the tree and graph/network representations that *d3.js* can import).

The [*networkx* JSON exporter](http://networkx.github.com/documentation/latest/reference/readwrite.json_graph.html) takes the form:

```
from networkx.readwrite import json_graph
import json
print json.dumps(json_graph.node_link_data(G))
```

Alternatively you can [export the network](http://networkx.github.com/documentation/latest/reference/readwrite) as a *GEXF* XML file and then import this representation into the [sigma.js](http://sigmajs.org/examples/gexf_example.html) Javascript visualisation library.

```
from xml.etree.cElementTree import tostring
writer=gf.GEXFWriter(encoding='utf-8',prettyprint=True,version='1.1draft')
writer.add_graph(G)
print tostring(writer.xml)
```

Answer (score 15):

Another option is [bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/) which just went to version 0.3.

Answer (score 11):

For those who recommended [pyd3](https://github.com/mikedewar/d3py), it is no longer under active development and points you to [vincent](https://github.com/wrobstory/vincent). vincent is also no longer under active development and recommends using [altair](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair).

So if you want a pythonic d3, use altair.

Answer (score 8):

Try https://altair-viz.github.io/ - the successor of d3py and vincent. See also

- https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/index.html
- https://speakerdeck.com/jakevdp/bespoke-visualizations-with-a-declarative-twist

Answer (score 5):

Check out [python-nvd3](https://github.com/areski/python-nvd3). It is a python wrapper for nvd3. Looks cooler than d3.py and also has more chart options.

Answer (score 5):

The library `d3graph` will build a force-directed d3-graph from within python. You can "break" the network based on the edge weight, and hover over the nodes for more information. Double click on a node will focus on the node and its connected edges.

```
pip install d3graph
```

Example:

```
source = ['node A','node F','node B','node B','node B','node A','node C','node Z']
target = ['node F','node B','node J','node F','node F','node M','node M','node A']
weight = [5.56, 0.5, 0.64, 0.23, 0.9,3.28,0.5,0.45]

# Import library
from d3graph import d3graph, vec2adjmat

# Convert to adjacency matrix
adjmat = vec2adjmat(source, target, weight=weight)
print(adjmat)
# target  node A  node B  node F  node J  node M  node C  node Z
# source                                                        
# node A    0.00     0.0    5.56    0.00    3.28     0.0     0.0
# node B    0.00     0.0    1.13    0.64    0.00     0.0     0.0
# node F    0.00     0.5    0.00    0.00    0.00     0.0     0.0
# node J    0.00     0.0    0.00    0.00    0.00     0.0     0.0
# node M    0.00     0.0    0.00    0.00    0.00     0.0     0.0
# node C    0.00     0.0    0.00    0.00    0.50     0.0     0.0
# node Z    0.45     0.0    0.00    0.00    0.00     0.0     0.0

# Example A: simple interactive network
out = d3graph(adjmat)

# Example B: Color nodes
out = d3graph(adjmat, node_color=adjmat.columns.values)

# Example C: include node size
node_size = [10,20,10,10,15,10,5]
out = d3graph(adjmat, node_color=adjmat.columns.values, node_size=node_size)

# Example D: include node-edge-size
out = d3graph(adjmat, node_color=adjmat.columns.values, node_size=node_size, node_size_edge=node_size[::-1], cmap='Set2')

# Example E: include node-edge color
out = d3graph(adjmat, node_color=adjmat.columns.values, node_size=node_size, node_size_edge=node_size[::-1], node_color_edge='#00FFFF')

# Example F: Change colormap
out = d3graph(adjmat, node_color=adjmat.columns.values, node_size=node_size, node_size_edge=node_size[::-1], node_color_edge='#00FFFF', cmap='Set2')

# Example H: Include directed links. Arrows are set from source -> target
out = d3graph(adjmat, node_color=adjmat.columns.values, node_size=node_size, node_size_edge=node_size[::-1], node_color_edge='#00FFFF', cmap='Set2', directed=True)
```

[image: Examples of d3graph]

Interactive example from the titanic-case can be found here:
https://erdogant.github.io/docs/d3graph/titanic_example/index.html
https://erdogant.github.io/hnet/pages/html/Use%20Cases.html

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/d3graph/, 

https://github.com/erdogant/d3graph/, 

https://erdogant.github.io/d3graph/pages/html/index.html,  

https://towardsdatascience.com/creating-beautiful-stand-alone-interactive-d3-charts-with-python-804117cb95a7

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest using mpld3 which combines D3js javascript visualizations with matplotlib of python.

The installation and usage is really simple and it has some cool plugins and interactive stuffs.

http://mpld3.github.io/

Answer (score 4):

**Plotly** can do some cool stuffs for you [image]

https://plot.ly/

Produces highly interactive graphs that can be easily embedded withing the HTML pages for your private server or website using its off line API.

**Update:**
I am note sure about its 3D plotting capabilities, for 2D graphs is awesome
Thanks

Comment: Note that this is _chart_ visualization... The question requests _graph_ visualization. (I appreciate these phrases are commonly conflated!)

Answer (score 2):

You can also choose to serialize your data and then visualize it in D3.js, as done here:
[Use Python & Pandas to Create a D3 Force Directed Network Diagram](http://www.austintaylor.io/d3/python/pandas/2016/02/01/create-d3-chart-python-force-directed/) (It comes with a [jupyter notebook](https://github.com/austin-taylor/austin-taylor.github.io/blob/master/static/examples/force_directed/pcap_to_d3_visual.ipynb) as well!)

Here is the gist. You serialize your graph data in this format:

```
import json
json_data = {
  "nodes":[
    {"name":"Myriel","group":1},
    {"name":"Napoleon","group":1},
    {"name":"Mlle.Baptistine","group":1},
    {"name":"Mme.Magloire","group":1},
    {"name":"CountessdeLo","group":1},
  ],
  "links":[
    {"source":1,"target":0,"value":1},
    {"source":2,"target":0,"value":8},
    {"source":3,"target":0,"value":10},
    {"source":3,"target":2,"value":6},
    {"source":4,"target":0,"value":1},
    {"source":5,"target":0,"value":1},
  ]
}
filename_out = 'graph_data.json'
json_out = open(filename_out,'w')
json_out.write(json_data)
json_out.close()
```

Then you load the data in with d3.js:

```
d3.json("pcap_export.json", drawGraph);
```

For the routine `drawGraph` I refer you to the link, however.

Comment: I edited it now, but I didn't include the drawGraph routine which itself calls drawLinks and drawNodes. It would just be too cumbersome and the elements only make sense in the context of the whole html file.

Answer (score 1):

There is an interesting port of NetworkX to Javascript that might do what you want.  See http://felix-kling.de/JSNetworkX/

Comment: this might work.... can you refer me to documentation please? How would I output a graph from python into it this javascript library...? I want to generate it in python first ... or how would i load it?

Comment: I've actually never used JSNetworkX so I'm not sure how it works.

Comment: @EiyrioüvonKauyf: The input is the same as in Python, e.g. a list of lists or a dict of dicts. You could build the graph in Python, convert it to a list of lists and convert it to JSON.

Comment: Yes, definitely easy.  The examples here are simple and beautiful:http://felix-kling.de/JSNetworkX/examples/

Answer (score 0):

I've got a good example of automatically generating D3.js network diagrams using Python here: http://brandonrose.org/ner2sna

The cool thing is that you end up with auto-generated HTML and JS and can embed the interactive D3 chart in a notebook with an IFrame