# Is there any way to convert Matplotlib figure objects to SVG or D3 graph?

Tags: javascript, python, svg, matplotlib, d3.js

I am not satisfied with Matplotlib's dynamic interactive capability, but I have to rely on it for lots of time and efforts been spend in developing Matplotlib drawing functions. Just curious to know:

Is there any python package that can directly convert the matplotlib objects(not the output pic) to interactive web based graph(or some intermediate objects that can be processed later on by), such as SVG or D3 or others? Is it possible in theory ?

Any thought/tip on such conversion is welcome.

Comment: Check out Jake Vanderplas' matplotlib (mpl) to D3, called mplD3. It is quite good and I had no problems installing it. [link] (http://mpld3.github.io/)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such tool to the best of my knowledge. In theory, it's certainly possible to have something like that, but it would likely be non-trivial to implement.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977517/python-equivalent-to-d3-js) suggests using [d3py](https://github.com/mikedewar/d3py) to generate D3 graphs from Python and there's also [bokeh](https://github.com/continuumio/bokeh), which aims to allow you to generate D3-like graphs in Python. Neither is exactly what you're looking for, but you might be able to use them to get closer to what you want.

Comment: Thanks. I heard of the tools you mention but the bad thing is I have to reimplement the drawing function on new platform. I just try to find a shortcut that I can still use the existing matplotlib function/syntax to generate the more web-friendly pics.